# Как подключить карту Google (JS) если используешь webpack и pug

Tags: google-maps, webpack, pug

Вот такую ошибку выдает когда пытаюсь подключить
http://prntscr.com/hog3hi

**pug код**

script(src='https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&callback=initMap')

**js код**

let initMap = function() {
    let uluru = {lat: -25.363, lng: 131.044};
    let map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {zoom: 4, center: uluru});
    let marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: uluru, map: map});
};

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Надо было быть более внимательным просто)

Во первых юзал не свой api для карты

Во вторых проблема так же была в, что функция initMap не была глобальной.

Более подробно можно прочитать тут 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37656592/define-global-variable-with-webpack

Вот рабочий пример

Что вставляем в pug 
div#map
   script(src='[https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=Ваш__ключ__от__api&callback=initMap](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=%D0%92%D0%B0%D1%88__%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87__%D0%BE%D1%82__api&callback=initMap)', async defer)

Код который вставляем в js файл страницы

var initMap = () => {
   var uluru = {lat: -25.363, lng: 131.044};
   var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {zoom: 4, center: uluru});
   var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: uluru, map: map});
};

Очень важная часть.
Нужно задать что то одно или можно оба

global.initMap = initMap;

window.initMap = initMap;

Надеюсь это вам поможет